# Proper 'using' syntax for pointer-to-member variable

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

```
  struct MyStruct {
    typedef int MyStruct::*Ptr;  // my pointer-to-member type
    int foo, bar;
  };
```

This code works, but I'd like to bring it up-to-date with modern style and replace the `typedef` with a `using`. What's the right syntax to use? I've tried a bunch of options and I'm stuck; the only examples I can find are for pointer-to-member-*function* which is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `using` syntax just moves the identifier placement, the general case is that

```
typedef ............. foo ..............;
```

can be changed to

```
using foo = .............  .............;
```

Your case is no exception; the code could be `using Ptr = int MyStruct::*;`

Answer (score 2):

```
using Ptr = int (MyStruct::*);
```

And in general, `(MyStruct::*)` will appear wherever `*` appears in non-member pointers.

Comment: Note that the parentheses are unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @Brian Yeah, but I find it incredibly confusing without them.